# Model in QueryString?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So, I'm facing a problem here. I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application, and the final stage is to implement a search page feature that uses multiple filters to perform the search.

I've done a model class called SearchModel that has some properties, among em' is a collection of search filters. The problem is at the search results page. I need to preserve the whole SearchModel as search criteria and additional paging parameters. I'd like to add links to next and previous pages and stuff like that, only available by a GET request. If I enable GET I get a HUGE query string containing the whole model as follows:

`Documents/Search?CriteriaFilters[0].Field=OwnerUserName&CriteriaFilters[0].Type=Text&CriteriaFilters[0].Text=albert.sheppard&CriteriaFilters[0].TextMatchMode=Exactly`

And that's only using one filter with a small criteria text. Looks bad and nasty when I'm using 10+ filters.

How you pro's handle search and results pages with multiple filters without parsing the whole model to the query string? Query string encryption? If so, how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider the Post/Redirect/Get pattern as an alternative. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get and simply pass through the id of the search (possibly stored in your db/memcache).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ASP.NET MVC, but it should be done with POST. I understand many of your fields are unused in your example, but they might as well have values, and the size of GET is very limited. Or maybe you can come up with a very compressed way of representing your criteria. But still, POST is a lot better.

Comment: The problem of using a POST request is that it cannot be bookmarked or opened in a new window or tab since is not a link but a form to be sent...

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented search criteria URL using MVC as follows:

acer notebook >> Notebook >> 15.6in >> Core 2 Duo

http://myserver/SearchApp/Search/4/acer%20notebook/1/50-97-77868%2c50-111-76631?sort=0&catGrp=50

```
private
ActionResult SearchAction
(
  int siteId,
  string query,
  int? page,
  string options,
  SortType sortType,
  int catGroupId
)
{
  // Search code implementation
}
```

The above URL and controller translation is as follows:

Search - Action

4 - siteId

acer%20notebook - query

50-97-77868%2c50-111-76631 - options (it is a comma separated list of options), which represents 15.6in >> Core 2 Duo

0 - sortType

50 - catGroup

Hope this will help.

Comment: Is a nice place to start from.. now, i have 2 search filter types, one that is plain text and other that is date range filter.. text filter has options like "starts with", "ends with" and such... Any advice on including that?

Comment: As you initially looking for a model in GET request as parameter, and one of the possibility is to use XML serialization (text) in request as a string parameter. But it will make URL a bit long. The best still I would suggest is to use individual parameters and create as many overloaded method as you want. Date range parameters can also be defined, but handle everything via string representation, as I haven't tried DateTime as parameter.